# DOM-based open redirect vulnerability on Vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a vue application initiated with Vue-cli. 
Vue version: `2.6.11`
vue-router version: `3.2.0`

**Reproduction Link**
https://github.com/keyhangholami/dom-based-open-redirect

**Steps to reproduce**
Put 3 or more forwarding slashes in the URL + an arbitrary URL and a date formatted with slashes (e.g. http://www.localhost:3000///google.com?dob=11/10/1987 and hit `Enter`.

**Expected behaviour** 
See the 404 page when the URL is invalid (includes 3 or more than 3 slashes + date like that).

**What's actually happening?**
The app gets redirected to Google (or any arbitrary URL) including all query params even though I don't have any redirect rule and I have the following route to redirect to 404:

```js
{ path: '*', name: '404-page', component: Page404, props: false }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue.  I updated to:

vue 2.6.14

vue-router 3.5.3

vue-template-compiler 2.6.14

and that solved the issue.